# Draw bitmap over bitmap and set some pixels transparent

Tags: android, bitmap, transparency

I have a custom `View` and two `Bitmap`s. I draw the one above the other like this

```
canvas.drawBitmap(backImage,0,0,null);
canvas.drawBitmap(frontImage,0,0,null);
```

Before painting I set some pixels in the frontImage transparent using the `setPixel(...)` function of `Bitmap`

```
frontImage.setPixel(x,y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Instead of viewing backImage's pixels at x,y I see black color...

Comment: What do you use for new XferMode for your `Paint`?

Comment: I tried with no `Paint` as above and with XferMode  `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP` but I got the same result... black

Comment: Have you tried `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR`?

Comment: This produces the desired result at x,y but every other pixel becomes black...

Comment: Draw the rest of the bitmap with different `Paint` and Xfermode

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that at some point I abandoned this experimental project without overcoming my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a really simple solution to this. What is your source material for the images? If you are loading them from files all you may need to do is convert the source files to PNG's. PNG's maintain transparency information and most rendering engines will take this in to account when layering them together on the screen.

Comment: Obvious follow up question with a duh answer: Are you using an editor that preserves the transparacy information (photoshop or paint.net)? The more basic editors will save transparent information as the default background color.

Answer (score -1):

Another Possibility. I use this technique quite a bit in Java games on the PC. It uses a little transparency class I stumbled across a number of years ago at this location:

```
 /*************************************************************************
 * The Transparency class was also developed by a thrid party. Info
 * on its use can be found at:
 *
 * http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0265.html
 *
 *************************************************************************/
//Transparency is a "Static", "Inner" class that will set a given color
//as transparent in a given image.
class Transparency {
    public static Image set(Image im, final Color color) {
        ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() { //Inner - Inner class -- very bad
            // the color we are looking for... Alpha bits are set to opaque
            public int markerRGB = color.getRGB() | 0xFF000000;

            public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
                if ( ( rgb | 0xFF000000 ) == markerRGB ) {
                    // Mark the alpha bits as zero - transparent
                    return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;
                }
                else {
                    // nothing to do
                    return rgb;
                }
            }
        };
        //apply the filter created above to the image
        ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
    }
}
```

Taking a Java Image object as input it will take what ever color you give it and perform the math on the image turning the color transparent.

Good luck.

Comment: The question is clearly labeled "android", and Android doesn't have these classes.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that they did. This example was offered as a starting point, where the ask-er could working up an android specific version of their own. But thanks for stopping by to point out how wrong you thought I was.